# CSS: make absolute nested DIV align left

Tags: css, alignment, css-position, absolute

I have a dropdown with content. I'm trying to make the content align at 0px at the left of the screen. No matter what I try, it still remains aligned within its parent container.

Since the dropdowns are centred in the browser, I'm having difficulty getting it work go where I want.

http://jsfiddle.net/XkuHy/2/

```
<div id="sticky">
    <div id="nav">
        <div class="logo">logo</div>
        <span class="n list">browse</span>
        <span class="n list">search</span>
        <div class="n drop">
            <span>My Account</span>
            <div>
                hello, world!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

NOTE: CSS is *not* my strong suit.

NOTE 2: StackOverflow kept banging on about needed code and not just a link to jsFiddle - not sure why so ignore the code dumped as you can see it in the fiddle.

[image]

Comment: "StackOverflow kept banging on about needed code and not just a link to jsFiddle - not sure why" ... they don't own jsfiddle, what if it goes pop one day? It leaves thousands of questions with no context. You should really put all your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.content` box is being positioned relative to its parent, the `.n.drop` div because it has a relative positioning. If you remove the relative positioning from the `.n.drop` element you will find the `.content` element to position itself about where you want it. You may need to also add a `margin-top: 16px;` to the `.content` element to make it clear the menu.

You can see the updated demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/XkuHy/14/

Comment: From Chrome (on windows), I can see 'orld!' only! And from firefox I can see only "d!".

Comment: @sadaf2605, I'm not seeing that here and I'm not sure what might cause that without seeing it.

Comment: @sadaf2605, I see what caused this now, the window must have been less than 800px wide and the `nav` element has been set to absolute positioning. I updated the jsfiddle to remove the absolute positioning yet still be centered by adding: `margin: auto;` to its style.

Answer (score 2):

When you make its margin to 0px. It is going to 0px but with respect to its parent. So you can try margin of negative values to its css:

```
margin-left:-205%;
```

like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XkuHy/13/
or

```
left: -345px;
```

like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XkuHy/13/

But both of them has cross browser comparability issue.

I have solved this issue by adding this to css, where "hello world" has a class name of "dropmenu":

```
.drop:hover .dropmenu{
    position: fixed;
    top:  100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index:998;
    background-color:white; 
}
​
```

Surprise! surprise! I think it works! Check out:
http://jsfiddle.net/XkuHy/10/